# Is ObfuscationAttribute available for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, obfuscation

I cannot find it for silverlight, its also not available as version on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute.aspx

Just to be sure: is it not supported? Do they plan to add it in SL5 maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is not available in Silverlight. However you could add an ObfuscationAttribute attribute implementation to your project. Some obfuscation tools vendors have ready to use files for this. I believe Eazfuscator.NET does, for example.